# What are -dbg packages for?

Tags: application-development, package-management, debugging, debug, package-info

1- What are **-dbg** packages really for?

2- Is it a **good/bad** idea to install them for, ***at least***, my **preferred applications/packages**?

3- Does installing them for my **preferred applications/packages** helps developers on debugging bugs I **may** encounter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) They contain debugging symbols.

2) If you need to debug things locally, then yes, they are necessary to get the debugging symbols. However, -dbg packages are somewhat deprecated, and you should add the ddebs archive to get the dbgsyms packages instead, when possible.

3) Not usually. If you report a crash bug, the crash reporting server will rescan with the appropriate debug packages installed to get a full stack trace with symbols.